# How to solve an equation of third degree?

Tags: abstract-algebra, roots-of-unity, cubics

I'm trying to solve this equation $x^3+bx^2+cx+d = 0$ and try to follow the steps from my notebook, but I barely understand my writing.

$(x+b/3)^3+bx^2+cx+d-xb^2/3-b^3/27$

$(x+b/3)^3+bx^2+x(c-b^2/3)+d-b^3/27$

Let $y= x+b/3$

$y^3+qy+r = 0$

I found out that $ q = (c-b^2/3)$ and $ r = d + (2b^3-3bc)/27.$ Is it correct ?

Let $y= \alpha + \beta $

$(\alpha+\beta)^3+q(\alpha+\beta)+r = 0$

$\alpha^3+3\alpha^2\beta+3\alpha\beta^3+\beta^3+q(\alpha+\beta)+r = 0$

$\alpha^3+\beta^3+(3\alpha\beta+q)(\alpha+\beta)+r = 0$

Then it says that $ \alpha^3+\beta^3 = -r $ and $\alpha\beta = -q/3 $. I can't figure out why.

Equation $t^2+rt-q^3/27=0 $ has the roots $ \alpha^3, \beta^3.$ I know this is from Vieta's formulas.

$ t_{1,2} = \frac {-r\pm\sqrt{r^2-4q^3/27}}{2}$

$\alpha_0 = \sqrt \alpha^3, \beta_0=\sqrt \beta^3$

$\alpha^3 = t_1$ has the roots $ \alpha_0,\epsilon\alpha_0,\epsilon^2\alpha_0.$

$\beta^3 = t_2 $ has the roots $ \beta_0,\epsilon\beta_0,\epsilon^2\beta_0.$

I'm lost here. I think that by $\epsilon$ he ment $\frac {cos2\pi}3 +i\frac {sin2\pi}3$. I don't understand why those are the roots.

The solutions of the equation $y^3+qy+r=0$ are $\alpha_0+\beta_0,\epsilon\alpha_0+\epsilon^2\beta_0,\epsilon^2\alpha_0+\epsilon\beta_0.$ Okay, but why ?

$ q = -1, r = 1.$ This makes no sense to me.

$\alpha_0 = \sqrt[3]{\frac {-1+\sqrt {1-4/27}}2} $

$\beta_0 = \sqrt[3]{\frac {-1-\sqrt {1-4/27}}2} $

$\alpha_0+\beta_0 \in R$

And that's all I have about cubic equations. I have the feeling that is uncomplete.

Comment: There are some nice answers in questions on the right side of the page under "related questions", which should show you how to solve cubic equations.

Comment: If your question is about understanding your own notes, this is a relatively individualized effort and you should really be the one to lead the project.  First, do you understand the overall approach?  Then, worry about understanding the details of the steps in that approach.

Comment: @SimpleArt I'm interested in this approach in particular. Maybe similar approaches.

Comment: @hardmath My question is about the algoritm and the steps that I don't understand.

Comment: :/ solving any polynomial algorithmic-ly should usually be done with Newton's method or similar.

Comment: Have you tried doing an example?  It would help you to find what you do and do not understand "about the algorithm".

Comment: @SimpleArt I'm not trying to solve any polynomial. I just want a simple algoritm for solving a cubic polynomial and I want to understand it.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, I have. And it didn't help me to understand what those steps do.

Answer (score 1):

Hints.

1) Transform the equation to the form $x^3 + 3bx + c$. I see you already did it. In your case you have the form $y^3 + qy + r$ which is exactly the same.

2) Smartass trick: let $y = w - \frac{b}{w}$. This transforms the equation into $$w^3 + c - \frac{b^3}{w^3} = 0$$ which is a quadratic in $w^3$. So solve this

3) You now have a value for $w$.

Can you find then a root now?

Answer (score 0):

The general strategy is to eliminate the quadratic term first, so as to have an equation in standard form $y^3+py+q=0$.

Then, Cardano's method replaces the single unknown $y$ by two unknowns $u$ and $v$ such that $y=u+v$. This introduces one degree of liberty, as physicists say. This allows to add a constraint, which will simplify the equation, namely  eliminating the term with factor $u+v$.

Finally it comes down to determining two numbers $u$ and $v$, knowing the sum of their cubes, and their product. A problem, which in turn comes down to determining $u^3$ and $v^3$, knowing their sum and their product – a classical problem on quadatic equations.